# Title of "gnome-terminal" is being overridden by .bashrc in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

I need to open around 20 terminals on the same time and execute different command on each one ,and I'd like also to name each window with a different name.

I'm using something as follows:

```
gnome-terminal --title="some title goes here" -- bash -ic "ls; exec bash"
```

The new window is opened , shows the title `some title goes here` and after 1~2 seconds
it's being overridden and turns into the path that I'm running the command

```
 gnome-terminal --title="some title goes here" -- bash -ic "ls; exec bash"
```

from.

Here is my `.bashrc`:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

[ -f ~/.fzf.bash ] && source ~/.fzf.bash

# function
parse_git_branch() {
  if [ -n "$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2> /dev/null)" ]; then
    echo "($(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)) "
  fi
}

# environment customization
# PS1="[\t \D{%F} \u@\h \W\a]$ "
PS1="$PS1-[\t \D{%F}]$ "
export PS1="$PS1\$(parse_git_branch)"


# HSTR configuration - add this to ~/.bashrc
alias hh=hstr                    # hh to be alias for hstr
export HSTR_CONFIG=hicolor       # get more colors
shopt -s histappend              # append new history items to .bash_history
export HISTCONTROL=ignorespace   # leading space hides commands from history
export HISTFILESIZE=10000        # increase history file size (default is 500)
export HISTSIZE=${HISTFILESIZE}  # increase history size (default is 500)
# ensure synchronization between bash memory and history file
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -n; ${PROMPT_COMMAND}"
# if this is interactive shell, then bind hstr to Ctrl-r (for Vi mode check doc)
if [[ $- =~ .*i.* ]]; then bind '"\C-r": "\C-a hstr -- \C-j"'; fi
# if this is interactive shell, then bind 'kill last command' to Ctrl-x k
if [[ $- =~ .*i.* ]]; then bind '"\C-xk": "\C-a hstr -k \C-j"'; fi


function changeTitle(){
  if [[ -z "$ORIG" ]]; then
    ORIG="$PS1"
  fi
  TITLE="\[\e]2;$*\a\]"
  PS1="${ORIG}${TITLE}"
}

### ALIASES ###
alias k='kubectl'
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: One simple thing you can try is to use `-- bash -c` instead of `-- bash -ic` in order to bypass reading .bashrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prompt set in `PS1` contains screen control codes which overwrite the window title.

If you don't want the prompt to change your window title, take out the snippet which does that.

Here's a slight edit to let you set `no_title_change` in the calling shell. This would replace the similar snippet in your current `.bashrc`; the real change it that we change the variable `$TERM` to a slightly more complex (and slightly hacky) [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
...

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
# unless $no_title_change is set
case ${no_title_change-$TERM} in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

...
```

If you unconditionally want to remove the title-changing logic, just replace this snippet with nothing.

The use case of opening a separate terminal window for each in a set of tasks is dubious; a better practice generally is to run your tasks as background processes, each with output to a file. Then you can automate monitoring and logging for the entire scenario, and avoid silly problems like terminating a process by mistake by accidentally closing the wrong terminal window; and managing the processes remotely from multiple locations becomes feasible.

Comment: Thanks ,but how do I use `no_title_change` in a terminal bash ? I've put your code in my `.bashrc` , and tried this code : `gnome-terminal --title="Hello" -- bash -ic "ls; exec bash"` , but it still takes a default name of the window ("Terminal").

Comment: `no_title_change=yes bash` runs Bash with the variable set. I would expect `no_title_change=yes gnome-terminal` to work similarly, though there may still be differences around how exactly `gnome-terminal` runs Bash.

Comment: Wait, do you mean the  window title is literally "Terminal"? Then that's not done by Bash at all, or at least not by the code you have shown us.